# Нужны ли указанные запятые? 3

Tags: пунктуация

Конкурентоспособность арматурной отрасли (,) как одного из секторов национальной обрабатывающей промышленности (,) невозможно рассматривать без ее взаимосвязи с конкурентоспособностью, с одной стороны — российского государства, и с другой стороны, — конкретных научных и производственных организаций.

Не могу понять, здесь оборот в значении "в качестве" и тогда запятые не нужны или здесь "одного из секторов..." приложение и тогда запятые оправданны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае  оборот с как представляет собой приложение и выделяется запятыми, т.к. оборот зависит не от сказуемого, а существительного. 
Оборот ***с как*** со значением ***"в качестве"*** всегда является частью сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо. Прояснили.

Comment: Серж,   вот предложение: Как художник  Лев Толстой гениален.   Здесь оборот тоже является частью сказуемого?

Comment: В данном случае приложение не обособляется, т.к. характеризует предмет с одной стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно поставить знаки в препинания в предложении, смысл которого не очень понятен, а здесь именно такой случай.

С трудом прослеживается такая мысль: арматурная отрасль - это важный сектор НАЦИОНАЛЬНОЙ промышленности, поэтому ее конкурентоспособность  - это конкурентоспособность не только конкретных научных и производственных организаций, но и всего ГОСУДАРСТВА в целом. Если это так, то  мы имеем обособленное приложение со значением причины.

Получается:

Конкурентоспособность арматурной отрасли, как одного из секторов национальной обрабатывающей промышленности, невозможно рассматривать  без ее взаимосвязи с конкурентоспособностью, с одной стороны — российского государства и, с другой стороны - конкретных научных и производственных организаций.